# Wordpress cyrillic encoding

Tags: php, mysql, html, wordpress, wamp

So i created a wordpress theme and the cyrillic characters in my .php files are not displayed correctly (for example front-page.php). I tried to change my php.ini file as following:

```
;default_charset = "UTF8"
;mssql.charset = "UTF8"
```

and the charset in the header.php:

```
<meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>">
```

//which should return utf8 as written in wordpress codex.

But it didnt work. I created another file index1.php in my theme directory. And when i preview it the text in cyrillic is shown properly. And I think that the problem is with Wordpress (because otherwise everything is fine). My WP database is with utf8_general_ci.
I am using wamp, localhost, Wordpress - 3.6.1

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try create .htaccess in root with content:

> ```
> AddDefaultCharset utf-8
> ```

and check, please, encoding of your template files, maybe you creates template in other encoding, not utf-8.

Comment: how should i check this?

Comment: try open file in you browser directly and look at the Page Encoding in menu of it. it is the simplest way. I always checks it on my PhpStorm in the bottom

Comment: and what encoding when you load wordpress page with your template?

Comment: This is in my theme.. If i am in Notepad++ and try to run the file the php wont work.. i see the whole code

Comment: Another think: before rendering place code: `header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');`

Comment: where should this go? in my header.php?

Comment: I don't know the structure of wordpress template. In Joomla I'll set it on the begging of index.php of template. Place it php code to the file, which loads first on using your template

Comment: anyways, i put the code in different places but it didnt work. Thanks! :)

Comment: it's very strange, have you tried your template on real workpress, worked in apache? Maybe it's notepad++ work incorrect?!

Answer (score 0):

Glory be to God! Finally it is solved.

I used Notepad++ and i should only go to the menu above **Encoding**-->**Convert to UTF-8 without BOM**. (I think only UTF-8 does the same thing.) You'd better go to Settings--->New Document/Default Directory---> Encoding and choose UTF-8 (or UTF-8 without BOM) and save these settings.

This is important! Be sure that your files are UTF-8.